# Setting up timeouts for every entry that are present in a HashMap

Tags: java, timertask

I have a HashMap in which I want to do a specific action for an entry that is added in the HashMap after a time period.

```
HashMap<K,V> map = new HashMap<>();
void addEntry(K,V) {
    //set timeout for the key-value pair to say 10 seconds
    map.put(K,V);
}

void actionAfterTimeout(K) {
    //do something
    map.remove(K);
}
```

Say after the timeout occurs i want to do some processing and remove the entry from the map. How should I do it?

Comment: It's not a trivial task. Have you considered using an existing cache api? May not do exactly what you want, because they don't usually evict on a timeout (only detect that a timeout occurred and re-fetch on the next client call).

Answer (score 2):

Use `Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)`.

```
HashMap<K,V> map = new HashMap<>();
Timer timer = new Timer();
long timeout = 10_000; // milliseconds

void addEntry(K key, V value) {
    //set timeout for the key-value pair to say 10 seconds
    map.put(key, value);

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            actionAfterTimeout(key);
        }
    }, timeout);
}

void actionAfterTimeout(K key) {
    //do something
    map.remove(key);
}
```

Comment: Will a new timer be started for every entry added to the HashMap if timer is created outside the addEntry() function?

Comment: you can do it so if you want.

Comment: A `Timer` is created once. Every time `addEntry` is called, a new `TimerTask` will be scheduled to run sometime in the future. If `addEntry` isn't called, then no `TimerTasks` will run.

Does that help?

Comment: Is this thread safe

Answer (score 0):

This one will work if you don't want to use multiple threads. It's not threadsafe.
It will perform processing on your first hit to the Map after the timeout has occurred.

```
class TimedMap<K, V>
{

    private Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<K, Long> timerMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    private static final Long TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS = 10000;

    public void addEntry( K key, V value )
    {
        checkTimeout();
        map.put( key, value );
        timerMap.remove( key );
        timerMap.put( key, System.currentTimeInMillis() );
    }

    public void getEntry( K key )
    {
        checkTimeout();
        map.get( key );
    }

    private void checkTimeout()
    {
        List<K> removals = new LinkedList<>();
        for( K key : map.keySet() )
        {
            if( ( System.currentTimeMillis() - 
                      timerMap.get( key ) ) > 
                  TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS )
            {
                removals.add( key );
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        for( K removal : removals )
        {
            actionAfterTimeout( key );
        }
    }

    private void actionAfterTimeout( K key )
    {
        //do something
        map.remove( key );
    }
}
```